# How do I disable Clamav from downloading virus database from Internet

Tags: centos, antivirus, clam

I have clamav software installed in my Server (Centos 7) which is under a corporate proxy. I want to stop clamav from trying to download virus databases everytime I try to run freshclam. I'm updating the .cvd files manually every month or so. So how do I stop clamav from downloading frequently.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit file:

```
/etc/freshclam.conf
```

find the following line

```
Checks 24
```

Then change the number to `0`

```
Checks 0
```

Or you can stop the cron record for `freshclam`